# Alterar tamanho do vetor da classe

Tags: java, servlet, array, declaração-de-variável

Eu tenho que usar o vetor `public static String vetor[] = new String [15];` na classe... porém essa classe eh usada em um servlet. E o tamanho que preciso do vetor é o que o usuário escolher... como posso passar o parâmetro que define o tamanho do vetor. Sei que esse 15 é só representativo... eu preciso de uma variável, mas como declarar um vetor da classe usando uma variável que vem do servlet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes resolver isso instanciando o vetor no construtor da classe e receber o tamanho como argumento:

```
public class Teste
{
   public static String vetor[];
   ...
   public Teste(int tamanhoVetor)
   {
       vetor = new String [tamanhoVetor];
   }
}
```

Na `Servlet` poderia ser algo como (a forma de pegar o valor pode ser diferente):

```
...
Teste testando = new Teste(Integer.valueOf(request.getAttribute("txtTamanho").toString()));
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se você está trabalhando com JSP, porém se estiver, precisa usar o Request para isso

```
   request.setAttribute("key", "valor") //set uma variavel de request

   RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/teste.jsp"); 
   rd.forward(request, response);

   String valor = (String) request.getAttribute("key"); //pega o request na sua classe jsp

   String meuArray[] = new String[valor]; //Set o valor passado no seu Array =)
```

Comment: isso eu ja faço... meu problema é só na parte do vetor(array) do Java

Comment: É só você pegar

`String valor = (String) request.getAttribute("key");
String meuArray = new String[valor];`

Comment: Edita sua resposta, para eu retirar o voto negativo... são as normas.

Comment: Editei, eu não fui muito claro na resposta, me desculpe, espero ter ajudado =D

Comment: Ainda assim o `meuArray` não é um array, corrija ai @DaniloOliveira. :)

Comment: Certo, que falta de atenção minha...